# Why is my GCP custom Dataflow template not generated but no errors are output?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

There is an older answer to this question but it doesn't seem to help in this case.

I am trying to create a GCP Dataflow Custom template with some code from a GCP example.   Here is the python code, its a GCP example [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#using-valueprovider-in-your-functions) with a few file paths changed and pipeline options added:

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.value_provider import StaticValueProvider
from apache_beam.io import WriteToText

class UserOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
      parser.add_value_provider_argument('--templated_int', type=int)

class MySumFn(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, templated_int):
      self.templated_int = templated_int

    def process(self, an_int):
      yield self.templated_int.get() + an_int

pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(
    runner='DataflowRunner',
    project='inspired-studio-111111',
    job_name='unique-job-name',
    temp_location='gs://positions_temp_bucket/temp',
    region='us-central1')
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

user_options = pipeline_options.view_as(UserOptions)
sum = (p
     | 'ReadCollection' >> beam.io.ReadFromText('gs://bucket2/data.txt')
     | 'StringToInt' >> beam.Map(lambda w: int(w))
     | 'AddGivenInt' >> beam.ParDo(MySumFn(user_options.templated_int))
     | 'WriteResultingCollection' >> WriteToText('gs://bucket1/out.txt'))
```

In cloud SDK I am running this command, again basically a GCP example found [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#creating-and-staging-templates):

```
C:\Projects\gcp_templates>python -m googlesample --runner DataflowRunner --project inspired-studio-111111 --staging_location gs://temp_bucket/staging --temp_location gs://temp_bucket/temp --template_location gs://dw_custom_template/templates/custom
```

There are no errors output, and there is no template generated at gs://dw_custom_template/templates/.  I already sorted through a number of permissions issues running the above command, and if I introduce a compile error in the python code I see it output with a run the gcloud command.  But here I am sorta stuck.

Another (possibly better) question: does anyone know where I can find another example of how to create a custom dataflow template?

Comment: Just to check - `--staging_location` and `--temp_location` are correct (exist and you have relevant IAM permissions) as well? Don't remember from the top of my head - is the `--region` - mandatory or optional?

Comment: A couple thoughts that may help you. First, I though perhaps using different buckets for staging and the final template could be the issue but I tried and I managed to do it successfully. Second, after running the command to create the template navigate to Logging and use the advanced filter `"template"
protoPayload.methodName="storage.objects.create"`, you should find the entry that creates the template and I suspect you will find more details into why is not being created.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. I followed the documentation provided [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#creating-and-staging-templates) but the template file is not generated.